# Statefulset with replicas : 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop, statefulset

I'm trying to setup , in my single node cluster (Docker Desktop Windows), an elastic cluster.
For this, I have created the PV as followed (working)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elastic-pv-data
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: elasticdata
  accessModes:   
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data/elastic"
```

Then here is the configuration :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: esnode
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: es-cluster # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 2
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: es-cluster
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      initContainers:
      - name: init-sysctl
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        resources:
            requests:
                memory: 1Gi
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          runAsUser: 1000
          capabilities:
            add:
            - IPC_LOCK
            - SYS_RESOURCE
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.7.1
        env:
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                  name: es-config
                  key: ES_JAVA_OPTS
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            scheme: HTTP
            path: /_cluster/health?local=true
            port: 9200
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: es-http
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: es-transport
        volumeMounts:
        - name: es-data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: es-data
      spec:
        storageClassName: elasticdata
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 3Gi
```

And the result is only one "pod" has its pvc binded to the pv, the other one gets an error loop "0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims".
Here is the *kubectl get pv,pvc* result :

```
NAME                               CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                      STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/elastic-pv-data   20Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/es-data-esnode-0   elasticdata             14m

NAME                                     STATUS   VOLUME            CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/es-data-esnode-0   Bound    elastic-pv-data   20Gi       RWO            elasticdata    13m
```

If I undestood correctly, I should have a second persistantolumeclaim with the following identifier : es-data-esnode-1
Is there something I miss or do not understand correctly ?
Thanks for your help

*I skip here the non relevant parts (configmap,loadbalancer,..)*

Comment: Have you tried changing  accessModes:   - ReadWriteOnce to ReadWriteMany ?  This will enable the volume to be mounted from many nodes.

Comment: just to clarify, I am talking about persistent volume and not persistent volume claim. pic should have readWriteOnce as it will be created one for each replica by statefulset

Comment: Please provide output of `kubectl get -o yaml sc/elasticdata`

Comment: The ReWriteOnce/readWriteMany should makes no differences in a [single node cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)
    `ReadWriteOnce -- the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node
    ReadOnlyMany -- the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes
    ReadWriteMany -- the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes`

Comment: @Lukman, here is the command's result : `Error from server (NotFound): storageclasses.storage.k8s.io "elasticdata" not found`

Comment: How were you able to create the PVC if the storage class is not found?? Did you run the command on the same cluster???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me add a few details to what was already said both in comments and in [Jonas's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213269/jonas) answer.

Inferring from the comments, you've not defined a `StorageClass` named `elasticdata`. If it doesn't exist, you cannot reference it in your `PV` and `PVC`.

Take a quick look at how `hostPath` is used to define a `PersistentVolume` and how it is referenced in a `PersistentVolumeClaim`. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume) you can see that in the example `storageClassName: manual` is used. Kubernetes docs doesn't say it explicitely but if you take a look at [Openshift docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/storage/persistent_storage/persistent-storage-hostpath.html#hostpath-static-provisioning_persistent-storage-hostpath), it says very clearly that:

> A Pod that uses a hostPath volume must be referenced by manual
> (static) provisioning.

It's not just some value used to bind `PVC` request to this specific `PV`. So if the `elasticdata` `StorageClass` hasn't been defined, you should't use it here.

Second thing. As [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213269/jonas) already stated in his comment, there is one-to-one binding between `PVC` and `PV` so no matter that your `PV` still has enough capacity, it has been already claimed by a different `PVC` and is not available any more. As you can read in the official [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#binding):

> **A PVC to PV binding is a one-to-one mapping**, using a ClaimRef which is
> a bi-directional binding between the PersistentVolume and the
> PersistentVolumeClaim.
>
> Claims will remain unbound indefinitely if a matching volume does not
> exist. Claims will be bound as matching volumes become available. For
> example, **a cluster provisioned with many 50Gi PVs would not match a
> PVC requesting 100Gi. The PVC can be bound when a 100Gi PV is added to
> the cluster.**

And vice versa. If there is just one 100Gi PV it won't be able to safisfy a request from two `PVC`s claiming for 50Gi each. Note that in the result of `kubectl get pv,pvc` you posted, both `PV` and `PVC` have capacity of `20Gi` although you request in each `PVC` created from `PVC` template only `3Gi`.

You don't work here with any dynamic storage provisioner so you need to provide manually as many `PersistentVolumes` as needed for your use case.

By the way, instead of using `hostPath` I would rather recommend you using [`local`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local) volume with properly defined [`StorageClass`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local). It has a few advantages over `HostPath`. Additionally *an external static provisioner can be run separately for improved management of the local volume lifecycle*

Answer (score 0):

When using a `StatefulSet` with `volumeClaimTemplates`, it will create a `PersistentVolumeClaim` for each replica. So if you use `replicas: 2`, two different PersistentVolumeClaims will be created, `es-data-esnode-0` and `es-data-esnode-1`.

Each `PersistentVolumeClaim` will bound to an unique `PersistentVolume`, so in the case of two PVCs, you would need two different `PersistentVolumes`. But this is not easy to do using `volumeClaimTemplate` and `hostPath`-volumes in a desktop setup.

For what reasons do you need `replicas: 2` in this case? It is usually used to provide better availability, e.g. using more than one node. But for a local setup in a desktop environment, usually a single replica on the single node should be fine? I think the easies solution for you is to use `replicas: 1`.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for this explanation, but I need to build an Elastic cluster, so at least 2 instances.
And I use the VolumeClaimsTemplates to create the two PersistantVolumesClaims, but it's not working. Only the first one is created and bound to the PersistantVolume, the other is not.

`Each PersistentVolumeClaim will bound to an unique PersistentVolume` is interesting, because i thought that it was linked only by StorageClassNameand capacity.
Each pvc needs 3Gi, a total of 6Gi. The PV has 20Gi to offer. And they share the same StorageClassName. Is is not enough ?

Comment: It does not work with two PVC when you only have one PV. When using two PVC, you need two PV.